# Cannot access to Desktop and Downloads folders in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just installed Anaconda-Navigator to my new M1 Macbook Air (Big Sur 11.2), and I found that **I cannot access to Desktop and Downloads folders in Jupyter Notebook.**
Other folders are accessible as usual, for example, Music, Movie and any other folders/documents I have in '/Users/(my username)/'.
I've used Jupyter Notebook for two years in my old Macbook Air 2018, and I didn't have any problem like this before.

I've deleted and reinstalled Anaconda-Navigator several times, and the folders are shown normally  in Jupyter Lab. Are there any other ways that I can try more?

---

**THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED**

Originally, Terminal had the access for the whole disk, but in new M1 Macbook, I had to give right to access to Download/Documents/Desktop folders to the Terminal.

Comment: What is the Path for Desktop and Downloads in your MAC and what error you get, or you just can't see the desktop/Download folder??

Comment: The path for Desktop and Downloads are '/Users/(my user name)/Desktop' and '/Users/(my user name)/Downloads'. Yes I just can't see those folders. I'll add the Screenshot of the Jupyter Notebook. Thank you!

Comment: Oh I cannot insert images yet... Did I make my self clear for explaining the problem?:(

Comment: I figured out how to solve the problem! Thank you!!

Comment: Hi there @ZhenZhuMin would u mind sharing how you solved this problem? i'm facing this same issue in my new M1 Pro Macbook. My OS is Monterey.

Comment: Hi @user12575866, My OS is Big Sur, so maybe there might be a little bit of difference. As I mentioned above in the last paragraph, I gave the access authority for the whole folders to the terminal. You can find it through 'Settings - Security & Privacy (menu) - Privacy (tab) - Files and Folders' and check the access of your terminal. Hope this helps you.:)