# save processed data in a Github python program

Tags: dataframe, github, jupyter-notebook, syntax-error, data-processing

I am doing research on breast cancer, using a combination of METABRIC dataset and other public data sets. It takes a lot of time to preprocess and bring them together for the next steps of analysis with my algorithms. A Kaggle member apparently has done it, as part of his research article. I have copied the jupyter notebook, and editing it myself.

I need to add a cell at some point in the notebook to save this data as a .cvs file and download it to my laptop for later use. Of course, the final results that run OK and yield reliable outcomes will be posted and publicly available.

Here is the code snippet. I want to save 'df' on my laptop:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('../input/breast-cancer-metabric/Breast Cancer METABRIC.csv', index_col = 0)

print(f'METABRIC Dataset Shape: {df1.shape}')
print(f'METABRIC Dataset Memory Usage: {df1.memory_usage().sum() / 1024 ** 2:.2f} MB')

df2 = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/breast-cancer-omics-bulk-data/METABRIC.txt', sep = '\t', index_col = 0)
df2 = df2.transpose()
print('Omics data shape', df2.shape)

i2 = [s.replace('BRCA-METABRIC-S1-','') for s in df2.index ]
print('number of common ids:', len(set(i2) & set(df1.index) ) )
df2.index = i2
df = df1.join(df2, how = 'inner')
```

I tried using the OS (Mac) and give it the path:

```
import os

# Set file path and name
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'metabric_data.csv')

# Save dataframe as CSV file
df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
```

but it doesn't work, I get error:

---

```
.....
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/Desktop/metabric_data.csv'
```

---

this doesn't make sense, because 'df' is defined in the previous cell and runs OK, and its output is:

> METABRIC Dataset Shape: (2509, 33)
> METABRIC Dataset Memory Usage: 0.65 MB
> Omics data shape (1980, 24360)
> number of common ids: 1980
> Joined data shape (1980, 24360)

Comment: Jupyter doesn't necessarily have access to your entire system. Could it just be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66012405/8508004)? (Or [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11350#issuecomment-546697846)?) You can use `%cd`, in conjunction with `ls` use, inside your notebook to see see where and what the kernel can access & see. If that isn't it, could you update your post to be clearer on where you are running Jupyter & how you installed it? I suspect it is locally running? But perhaps not? There's a lot of ways to install/access Jupyter.